# C# 2.0 Execution Time Timer

Tags: c#, performance, timer, stopwatch, execution-time

I would like to be able to calculate the amount of time a number of functions take to execute.  I was thinking about using some type of stopwatch class. I can call start/stop before and after each function call, however that seems horribly ugly to me. Is there a way to do this without a stopwatch class? Can something in the Reflections class help with this?

Thanks in advance for you input.

Comment: What's wrong with the Stopwatch (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch) class?

Comment: There is nothing _wrong_ with it.  If that is the best way, then I am fine with that.  Just looking for something a little more dynamic and wanted to avoid littering my code with start/stops.

Comment: @Martinho: J.Hendrix wants to profile every single function call. That's doable with Stopwatch but it's probably not the best solution for solution-wide profiling. Note the answers below suggest external profilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think u must try the PostSharp way http://www.postsharp.org/

Changing the code in the sample for this one:

```
public class ProfileMethodsAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect 
{ 
  public override void OnEntry( MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs) 
  { eventArgs.MethodExecutionTag = Stopwatch.StartNew();  } 

  public override void OnExit( MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs) 
  { 
     // Here u can get the time
     Console.WriteLine(((Stopwatch)eventArgs.MethodExecutionTag).ElapsedMilliseconds);
  } 
}
```

You can get the time off any method

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the sponsor of the performance tag ... [Red Gate Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm).  You can get a demo that will run your app and give you performance information for every line and every method that your app hits while it is being profiled.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should think about using code profiling... Use an external application like [Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler&gclid=CJuQhYuFkJ8CFVw55QodM1gmSw) to profile your code? Ants is from Red Gate and not free but i think that there are a some free/open source apps out there as well.

Some [free/open source profilers here](http://en.csharp-online.net/Open_Source_Profilers)...

It's ok to stopwatch a method here and there but trying to do that for every method in your solution would quickly become unwieldy.

Comment: I will take a look at Ants.  My thought was to be able to turn it on and off using some sort of flag.  I want to be able to run it in a production environment to help trouble shoot network, SQL, or other IO bottle-necks.

Answer (score 1):

you could put the stopwatch class into an attribute used to decorate your methods, i.e. the AOP style. check out [this](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/09/27/PostSharpAOPUnityIoCContainerAlternativeInterceptionExtensionRemotePolicyInjector.aspx)

Comment: +1 Nice!  I think this is what I am looking for.  I have never decorated a method before.  Will this work in 2.0?  Do I need to add any references to the project?

Answer (score 0):

There are various timers. `System.Timers.Timer` would be one such. But as the previous answer suggests, are you sure this is the right solutio to the problem you're actually trying to address?

Comment: No, I'm not sure.  I have a few ideas, but very open to suggestions.  Thanks!